# Can you recognize this file format as parseable?

Tags: binary, hex, file-format

I'm a technologist at a news company and inherited systems that never migrated our old stories out of the first CMS iteration. I'd like to do so, but the cost of software support is many thousands of dollars. No matter: they are plaintext-ish and it appears I can extract the contents.

Can anyone recognize this file format as parseable for programmatic extraction?

Here are the original files per @Jongware's help in the comments:

https://github.com/mcnaughton/mystery/blob/master/1?raw=true
https://github.com/mcnaughton/mystery/blob/master/2?raw=true
https://github.com/mcnaughton/mystery/blob/master/3?raw=true

Here are the hex dumps:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcnaughton/mystery/master/hexdumps/1
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcnaughton/mystery/master/hexdumps/2
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcnaughton/mystery/master/hexdumps/3

Here is an example of a useless ASCII version: https://gist.github.com/buley/3acd74d2bf418520c309

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to identify files for you.

Comment: I'd like to programmatically extract the contents of these files and I'm trying to find what format language in which "to speak." This is the written output of a programmed data structure and I can't think of a better place to find someone who may recognize it.

Comment: The "textual" version is *useless*. Post the original binary form somewhere if you want help with it. ("Useless" because some parts are translated into some sort of ASCII representation, some characters are translated into `?` or obviously missing.)

Comment: On it - thanks, Jongware.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Jongware, I've posted the original files. I was silly to assume it was an ASCII format. This format is locking in years of our community journalism and it would be an absolute treasure for us to recover.